# First part of postcode

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, postal-code

I want user to search by postcode, they could enter full postcode (eg: UB100PE / UB10 0PE) or first part of postcode (UB10)

I will use  `getUKPostcodeFirstPart("UB100PE")` to get first part of postcode

[Ref: getUKPostcodeFirstPart() by LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318220/php-get-the-first-part-of-postcode)

I want to display a list of record from first part of postcode, is this how it should be done?

Should I add `stripped_postcode` field in the table?

Something like::

```
SELECT records.company, records.full_postcode, area.* FROM records
  LEFT JOIN area on area.stripped_postcode = records.stripped_postcode AND records.id= area.record_id
WHERE records.stripped_postcode = "UB10"
```

It is linked with two tables, `records` and `area`

**record table:**

- id (PK)
- company
- postcode
- stripped_postcode

**area table:**

- id (PK)
- record_id (FK)
- stripped_postcode
- field1
- field2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused:  seems like a lot of work for avoiding the use of a like in SQL.

```
SELECT records.company, records.full_postcode, area.[insert your fields here]
FROM records
 LEFT JOIN area 
   ON area.stripped_postcode = records.stripped_postcode 
  AND records.id= area.record_id
WHERE records.postcode like strSearch+'%'
```

Comment: **Never use *, always define the fields.**